# After the Python script USES Pyinstaller to package into an exe executable Error

Tags: pyinstaller, python-multiprocessing, py2exe

It can run in a Python environment without error, and after encapsulating an exe file with Pyinstaller, call Multiprocessing to report the error

```
error: unrecognized arguments: --multiprocessing-fork parent_pid=197320 pipe_handle=4236
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Windows, and adding

```
multiprocessing.freeze_support()
```

right after `if __name__ == '__main__':` solved the issue.

I am using `pyinstaller` in my case.